# Series expansion of $ (1-\frac{1}{x})^x $ at infinity

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I'm trying to compute the expansion of $ (1-\frac{1}{x})^x $ at infinity, which is given by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-1%2Fx%29%5Ex%20taylor%20expansion) as
$$ \frac{1}{e} - \frac{1}{2ex} - \frac{5}{24ex^2} - \frac{5}{48ex^3} - \frac{337}{5760ex^4} + O(x^{-5}) $$

I tried substituting $ u = \frac{1}{x} $, but this doesn't help as the derivative of $(1-u)^{1/u} $ seems to be indeterminate at $ u = 0 $. What am I missing?

Comment: $(1-1/x)^x = \exp \left ( \ln \left ( (1-1/x)^x \right ) \right ) = \exp(x \ln(1-1/x))$. Expand the logarithm then expand the exponential.

Comment: Just use $\lim_{u\to 0}(1-u)^{1/u} = e^{-1}$ to define it at zero.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following expansions as $z\to0$
$$\begin{align*}
\log(1+z)&=z-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}-\frac{z^4}{4}+O(z^5) \\
e^z&=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+O(z^5).
\end{align*}$$
We have,
$$\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x&=\exp\left(x\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(x\left(-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{3x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(-1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{3x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{e}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{3x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{e}\left[1+\left(-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{3x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{3x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)^2+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{e}\left[1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{3x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{e}\left[1-\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{5}{24x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{2ex}-\frac{5}{24ex^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)
\end{align*}$$
as $x\to\infty$. These are only the first $3$ terms, but the procedure to obtain more should be clear.